# Can we use Optaplanner for service composition

Tags: optaplanner

I'm looking for a solution that could help to generate a composition of services that is able to satisfy a given goal of the user. A very simple example could be a composition that is able to provide the environmental temperature in Fahrenheit based on a composition of a service providing the temperature in Celcius and a service that is able to convert temperature from Celcius to Fahrenheit. As said this is a very simple, quite static composition but I'm facing much more dynamic cases where the available services change at runtime. In this case the continuous planning could be very handy.

Is this something that could be achieved using Optaplanner? Can you give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Johan,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like OptaPlanner would be a good fit. I 'd start with the Cloud Balancing tutorial. Basically your Goal is CB's Computer class and your Service is CB's Process class.

Then mix in Continuous Planning and/or Real-time Planning (see user guide docs for those) to deal with changes at runtime.